# Namespace error while converting Java to XML

Tags: java, xml-parsing, domexception

I'm trying to create an XML string like below using `Java`.

```
<entry gd:etag="*" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/contactid</id>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <gd:name>
    <gd:fullName>{Name}</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"
    primary="true"
    address="{Email}" displayName="Mani"/>
  <content type="text">Notes</content>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
    primary="true">{MobileNumber}</gd:phoneNumber>
</entry>
```

My java code is

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuildFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuildFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element entry = doc.createElement("entry");
entry.setPrefix("gd");  
entry.setAttribute("gd:etag","*");
doc.appendChild(entry);
Element id = doc.createElement("id");
id.setTextContent("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/"+contactID);
entry.appendChild(id);
Element category = doc.createElement("catagory");
category.setAttribute("scheme","http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind");
category.setAttribute("term","http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact");
entry.appendChild(category);
Element name = doc.createElement("gd:name");
Element fullName = doc.createElement("gd:fullname");
fullName.setTextContent(newName);
name.appendChild(fullName);
entry.appendChild(name);
....
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(entry);
TransformerFactory transformFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(source , result);
String xmlString = stringWriter.toString();
```

When I run the above code, I'm getting the following exceptions

> Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An
>   attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is
>   incorrect with regard to namespaces.
>   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.setPrefix()

Can someone suggest me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found where I'm went wrong. 
I just changed the below line in my code

```
Element entry = doc.createElement("entry");
```

to

```
Element entry = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","entry");
```

Now I got the XML string what I needed.